# Flutter The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Deposit?>?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Service:

```
static Future addDeposit(String amount, String product, String phone, String token) async {
    assert(token.isNotEmpty);
    try{
      Response<String> response = await _dio.post(
        'url',
          data: <String, String>{
            'amount': amount,
            'product': product,
            'phone': phone,
          
          },

      );
    
      if (response.statusCode == 200){
        return Deposit.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data  ?? '{}'));
      }else if(response.statusCode == 400){
        return Deposit.fromJson(response.data ?? '');
      }else{
        throw Exception(response.statusMessage);
      }
    }catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

```
child: FutureBuilder<Deposit?>(
  future: AuthService.addDeposit(amount, product, phone,),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Deposit?> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return _snapshotHasData(snapshot.data!);
    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }
    return const LinearProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

Error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Deposit?>?'.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Deposit' is from 'package:ias/models/deposit_model.dart' ('lib/models/deposit_model.dart').
  future: AuthService.addDeposit(amount, product, phone),

Comment: Can you include more about  `AuthService.addDeposit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add data return type

```dart
Future<Deposit?> addDeposit(String amount, String product, String phone, String token) async {
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: a new error is appeared Undefined name 'amount'.

Comment: feel free to create new question with proper snippet